# How can I properly use codepen pens with HTML CSS JS in a template?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I wanna use some beautifully designed elements from codepen in a template or design blocks. Should I put them in separate files or I can paste the codes in custom files? I wanna I avoid mixing the classes and properties with the main template's code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately if the codepen is using generic classes like "container" or something, you might have to make some adjustments before tossing it into your theme (ie change any references of 'container' to 'container--codepen-thing' for example). If it's something custom you're adding to your side, I'd make it as modular as possible and add the html/css/javascript to their own respective files and then add it into your theme, that way it's more easy to manage over time and it's not lumped in with the theme's default code.